# Compute average file size

Tags: bash, command-line

I am looking for a handy one-liner for computing the average file size in a directory.

What I want is:

size of all files / number of files in directory

Comment: As in the average size of each file in the directory? or the size of the directory?

Comment: The average size of a file in a directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With FreeBSD / Mac OS X `find`, `stat` and `awk` (not exactly a handy one-liner though):

```
find -x . -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec sh -c 'stat -f '%z' "${@}"' _ '{}' + | 
LC_ALL=C awk -v pwd="${PWD}" '
   BEGIN{ sum=0; count=0; }
   { sum+=$1; ++count; }
   END{ 
        if (count == 0) exit;
        printf ("number of files: %d\n", count); 
        printf ("average file size in B: %.5f\n", sum/count); 
        printf ("average file size in KB: %.5f\n", (sum/count) / 1024); 
        printf ("average file size in MB: %.5f\n", (sum/count) / (1024*1024)); 
        printf ("directory: %s\n", pwd); 
   }
'
```

Comment: Note that in `-v var=value`, `awk` will expand ANSI C sequences as `\n`, `\r`... While shells do export `PWD`, so you can use `ENVIRON["PWD"]` in `awk` which doesn't have that kind of problem for directories having backslashes in their name.

Comment: If you just need the average size in bytes, you can use `find . -type f -exec stat -f%z {} +|awk '{s+=$0}END{print s/NR}'`.

Answer (score 19):

With GNU find:

```
find . -type f -printf '%s\n' | awk '{s+=$0}
  END {printf "Count: %u\nAverage size: %.2f\n", NR, s/NR}'
```

Or for disk usage:

```
find . -type f -printf '%b\n' | awk '{s+=$0}
  END {printf "Count: %u\nAverage size: %.2f\n", NR, s*512/NR}'
```

Note that if there are several hardlinks of the same file in there, that will count its disk usage several time.

The above only counts regular files, not symlinks or directories or other special files. It includes hidden files.

The same with `zsh` builtins:

```
zmodload -i zsh/stat
count() {zstat -Hs -- $REPLY; ((size+=$s[size], count++, 0))}
size=0 count=0
**/*(oNDN.+count)
print -f "Count: %s\nAverage size: %.2f\n" $count $(($size./count))
```

Comment: This works but could do with being more human-readable - I assume the current output is in bytes. This should probably be made explicit and converted to something more explicit, like MB or GB.

Answer (score 3):

A simplistic solution in one line:

```
ls -Rl -- "$DIR" | awk 'BEGIN{sum=0;count=0};/^-/{sum+=$5;++count};END{print sum/count}'
```

It has a syntactic cheat in it, only considering `ls` output lines that begin with '-', which should constitutes data for regular files.

Answer (score 2):

for only files in a directory, ignoring sub directories:

```
expr $(du -Ss | cut -f1) / $(find /path/to/dir -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l)
```

Or to count all files including files in subdirectories:

```
expr $(du -s | cut -f1) / $(find /path/to/dir -type f | wc -l)
```

Comment: I'd like not to ignore sub directories.

Comment: nice. Just add -k to du invocation to have the result in 1024bytes (kb) instead of 512bytes (default size of a file chunk).

Comment: `du -s` will add up the **disk usage** (not size) of all the files **and directories and other non-regular files**, excluding extra hard links to the same file, while `find` will count all the regular files. Also, filenames with newline characters will be counted several times. `du -S` is GNU specific. `du -s` will report sectors or kilobytes depending on the OS.

Comment: As usual @StephaneChazelas your knowledge of linux/unix astounds me and shows me how dirty my quick and dirty solutions are. How long have you been using linux/unix?

Comment: Answer is horribly wrong and should be deleted. Explained by Stephane.