# How do I add the file size output together

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, command-line

```
158416
757249
574994
144436
520739
210444
398630
1219080
256965
684782
393445
157957
273642
178980
339245
6014031
```

These are the file sizes in my current directory. I got them using the command:

```
ls -l | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f5 | tail +2
```

Is there anyway that I can add all 15 of these sizes to get the total size of all the files using ONLY `cut, echo, eval, head, ls, tail, tr` commands

Comment: `ls` is not a tool intented to be parsed. Thanks to [**not** parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: A duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472672/how-do-i-add-together-the-output-of-command-line

Comment: Relating: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63370/compute-average-file-size

Comment: @JeffSchaller This appears to be an exact copy of the same question. Is it possible this is a HW task, or a dual account posting?

Comment: @alphaQ, which of those commands are intended for arithmetic?

Answer (score 3):

Put your numbers in a file called "file.txt", then

```
var=$(cat file.txt)
echo $((${var//$'\n'/+}))
```

Basically, the pattern in the arrhythmic expression is in the form:
`${parameter//find/replace}`, or in our example `${var// /+}`. This is *Bash parameter expansion*:

```
- `\n` will add blank spaces between the numbers in the list
- The double slashes `//` are for replacing all occurrences of space with `+` sign, if you put one slash `/`, only first space is going to be replaced. The space is there because you are replacing space with plus sign.
```

The previous solution can be simplified as follows:

```
var=echo $(< file.txt)
echo $((${var// /+}))
```

**However, both solutions suffer from *command substitutions* which may trim trailing newlines**

More [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution)

Comment: Ooh, I hadn't though of bash substitutions. Does this handle trailing newlines?

Comment: the `$(...)` command substitutions will trim trailing newlines: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution

Comment: @goro, that is fiendishly clever. I'm upvoting, but I feel a bit guilty doing it.

Comment: You are the master @glenn jackman. we keep learning from you! Thank you so much for sharing the link. I will take a look ;-)

Comment: Upvoted for using a single external command to do this. Could you maybe add a bit of description to the script so that vistors could learn from it?

Comment: You don't even need to call out to cat: `contents=$(< file.txt)` is pure bash.

Comment: @glenn jackman. Yep! I just was reviewing the link you had shared, thanks again for sharing!!!

Comment: Both `$(cat file)` and `$(<file)` strip trailing empty lines.

Comment: Ah OK, I saw that but thought that you were implying that only `$(<file)` (as opposed to `$(cat file)`) was stripping trailing empty lines. In any case, here the input is not meant to have any empty line, and if it had that would cause some syntax error in the arithmetic expansion.

Comment: Note that the description no longer matches the code.

Answer (score 3):

From that list of commands, none of them can add up numbers, so I suppose the idea is that the shell's arithmetic expansions have to be used.

Something like:

```
echo "$(($(LC_ALL=C ls -nq | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f5 | tail -n +2 | tr '\n' +)0))"
```

(here assuming none of the files are devices files for which the `ls -l` output doesn't have the size in 5<sup>th</sup> column but the device major number).

Note that the output of `ls -l` or `ls -n` varies between locales and is unspecified in locales other than `C`/`POSIX`.

Also, without `-q`, it wouldn't work for files whose name or symlink target contains newline characters.

**Not using `-q` would amount to an arbitrary command injection vulnerability** would you run the command in a directory where someone could create files with malicious names (try for instance after running `ln -s $'\nx x x x a[$(reboot)0]' x` without the `-q`)

You'd want `-n` instead of `-l` as with `-l` you get user/group names instead of ids which may contain space characters.

Note that `tail +2` is deprecated. The standard syntax is `tail -n +2`.

Answer (score 1):

Use bash's `$(( ))` for arithmetic:

```
ACC=0
for i in $(command to get sizes); do ACC=$((i + ACC)); done
echo $ACC
```

Comment: `$` is not needed on ordinary variables in arithmetic context (inside `$(( ... ))`).

Comment: @Kusalanda I didn't know that! I shall update the answer

Answer (score 1):

Using paste and bc :

```
$ paste -sd + file | bc
12283035
```

Comment: OP did say using ONLY `cut, echo, eval, head, ls, tail, tr` commands

Comment: Me said that `ls` is not a tool to be parsed ^^

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately this is the question we have been given. It is not an ideal situation, but these are the constraints we have, and we have to work within them.

Comment: Note that POSIX `paste` requires at least one filename argument, so portably, you'd want `paste -sd + file` or `paste -sd + - < file`. Note that `-l` is not necessary here.